# Need help making Easy Table (Wordpress Plugin) responsive

Tags: html, css, plugins, wordpress

I've made a menu using the Wordpress plugin "easy table" and now I'd like to make it responsive. I have things floating to the left and right and while viewing it on a mobile device, it looks insanely warped. I'd like some help fixing the positioning on this.

Here's some relevant HTML:

```
<div class="leftFloat">
<div id="menuHeader">
<h2>Appetizers</h2>
</div>
[tbl width="400" colwidth="50|50" colalign="left|right"]
Onion Rings-4.95
Fries-3.99
Nachos Supreme (small)-8.95
Nachos Supreme (large)-10.95
[/tbl]


<div id="menuHeader">
<h2>Fresh Salads</h2>
</div>
[tbl width="400" colwidth="100|50|50" colalign="left|right|right"]
-Small-Large
Garden Salad-4.95-5.99
Chef | Caesar| Greek-5.95-6.95
Add chicken for--2.00
[/tbl]
</div>

<div class="rightFloat">
<div id="menuHeader">
<h2>From the Grill</h2>
</div>
[tbl width="400" colwidth="100|50" colalign="left|right"]
Donair Burger-4.95
Hamburger-3.25
Cheeseburger-3.95
Big "J" Burger-5.95
Double Burger-5.95
Club Sandwich & Fries-6.95
BLT Sandwich & Fries-5.95
Lasagna & Garlic Bread-7.25
Chicken or Beef StirFry-8.95
Lebanese Shistawook-7.95
[/tbl]
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
```

And some CSS:
    .leftFloat{ float:left; }
    .rightFloat{ float:right; }

```
.clear{ clear:both; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this CSS:

```
.easy-table {
    width: 400px;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .leftFloat, .rightFloat {
        float : none;
    }

    .easy-table {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

And remove inline styling from the table(change `[tbl width="400" colwidth="50|50" colalign="left|right"]` to `[tbl colwidth="50|50" colalign="left|right"]`).

Answer (score 0):

If you need responsive design, using Responsive Grid System on your project. How does?

- http://960.gs/
- http://getbootstrap.com/
- they are my favorite or have more ...

**Simple responsive design: [Bootstrap]**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-4"> ... </div> 
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8"> ... </div>
        <!-- col-lg-6 = on large screen   -> 6/12 (50%)  "big computer" -->
        <!-- col-md-6 = on medium screen  -> 6/12 (50%)  "normal computer" -->
        <!-- col-sm-6 = on small screen   -> 6/12 (50%)  "tablet" -->
        <!-- col-xs-6 = on x-small screen -> 6/12 (50%)  "mobile" -->
        <!-- these are all standard screen pixel -->
    </div>
</div>
```

For more examples: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/